# searching for words that has space in Elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a problem in searching that has spaces in my fields with Elastic search.

```
const body = {
    query: {
        wildcard: {
            name: `${query}*`
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say I am searching the name of the cities. When I search "Los", It searches all cities that has substring "los" in it.

But when I search as "Los ang", it doesnt show "Los angeles".

Comment: could you please check whether it works if you search for `Los Ang` with capital A?

Comment: well, the moment that i put space there is not result

Comment: space destroy the search

Comment: can you try to send the same request to your cluster via curl? If that works, it may have something to do with the way your whitespace is encoded in your variable

Comment: two things: (1) please protect your cluster endpoint, it is publicly available; (2) it doesn't seem you're running a wildcard query, because if I search for "los" i get also "Paso de los Libres" which doesn't match the query in your message. Please give us the right information

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve it. Can u please have a look at it? and how I protect your cluster endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

After trying many other way, finally managed to get the result I wanted but still dont know whether this is the right way without wildcard.

```
const body = {
    size: 500,
    from: 0,
    query: {
        query_string: {
            fields: ["name"],
            query: `${query}*`,
            default_operator: "AND"
        }
    }
}
```